# rails paths are broken in docker container

Tags: docker, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a rails project which on `rails s` loads and runs fine. but when I containerize the application, required modules in lib folder are not loaded and could be not found in the docker file structure. how to correctly specify the paths? I dont want to have differentiate between docker and local filesystem.

I have tried different approaches but all of them are pointing to wrong directory

```rb
#application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

```
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN bundle install
```

```rb
#my_constants.rb (in config/initializers)
require_relative "#{Rails.root}/app/lib/sf"
PI = 3.14
```

when i ran in docker, the path in require is always one more /app deeper no matter I do.

is there any good tutorial for that? I am very confused. can somebody help me? thank you.

I have tried different approaches but all of them are pointing to wrong directory.
I dont want to have differentiate between docker and local filesystem.

Comment: Can you just `require 'sf'`, without manually adjusting paths at all?  In a Rails application I'd normally expect the `app` and `lib` directories to be on the search path without having to do extra configuration.

Comment: i did that and it still cant find my file. :(